# On a public wifi where are EAP messages (for the RADIUS AAA) actually created?

Tags: wifi

After doing quite a lot of research there's one part of providing public wifi I dont get:

**In what piece of software/hardware is the EAP packet created to send to my AAA server?**

I was only planning to have an access point and some type of gateway on the client side of the internet and then from the gateway a VPN connection to my AAA server.

My understanding is that EAP messages go to my RADIUS server in order to work out all the AAA details? They must originate from the client side somewhere??

Answer (score 0):

They're created in the 802.1X supplicant (also known as an "EAP over LAN" or "EAPOL" client) software in your wireless client machines. Most APs just receive the EAP messages via 802.1X, take off the 802.1X wrapping and then wrap it up in RADIUS, and ship it off to the RADIUS server (and vice-versa).